# How to modify guidewire stylesheet

Tags: java, gosu, guidewire

Is there s way to modify the stylesheet of Guidewire UI?
We are using Billing Center 7 and want to add a small css class for IE11 compatibility.
But we need to know which css file to modify.

Comment: interesting question... Have you tried to inspect the website to see which .css files are being used? I have worked with Claim Center 8 but not Billing Center 7 though, so I'm not sure if they would be the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at BillingCenter/modules/configuration/webresources/Ocean/css/gw_ext.css

We are using it to modify the CSS in our PolicyCenter 7, so I would think it should do the trick in your case.

Comment: I am using GW 7. Dont see this folder under configuration :(

Comment: Oh, one more thing, you have to call gwbc.bat dev-deploy to make changes visibe.